# How can I create a custom chart without JS besides Google Charts?

Tags: charts, images

**Questions**

Now that Google Image Charts are deprecated and only have a year or two left before they can shut it off.  Are there any other options out there for creating image based charts (as opposed to JS-based charts)?

**Background**

There are plentiful solutions for creating charts if you have JS as an option.  Visualforce has it's own charts, you can use the Google Charts API, but if you need to include the chart in a merge document or a pdf rendered visualforce page you can't use anything javascript based.  I've loved Google Charts even though they aren't always the prettiest, but they've been deprecated and I need to figure out a replacement.  So far I've been unable to google anything that's not javascript based.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I encountered the same issue recently and ended up using Conga Merge. I merged to Excel, used the data to create charts there and then exported as PDF. While it worked, I would really recommend it as it was very tedious.

Comment: Yep, that's where we're sending the charts.  We'd been doing chart merges in conga but the formatting always came out FUBAR, which led us to google image charts in the first place :(

Comment: Why can't you use a javascript library like D3 or chartJs for your use case? There are many apps on the Appexchange that use these libraries, in both Lightning and standard visualforce flavors.

Comment: @RobertSussland in general anything you want to print, email, or deal with configuratively (i.e. reports) doesn't support javascripts. Google image charts work great in these cases since all of them support img tags

Comment: Ahh, OK you want to print/grab an image, like via toDataUrl() from a canvas tag? That way you can use whatever JS you want to generate the chart on a canvas and then get a capture png to email out?

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, ChartURL is not a real drop-in replacement to Google Image Charts.

However there is actually **[Image-Charts](https://image-charts.com) a fully compatible replacement for Google Image Charts.

The only required change to VisualForce scripts is to replace `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart` by `https://image-charts.com/chart`.

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chdlp=b&chtt=Uberman&chdl=Asleep%7CAwake&chd=t:1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11&cht=p&chco=4ECDC4,C7F464
```

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=200x200&chdlp=b&chtt=Uberman&chdl=Asleep%7CAwake&chd=t:1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11&cht=p&chco=4ECDC4,C7F464
```

[image: Image-Charts.com an alternative to Google Image Charts]

**Bonus** it even supports animated charts through gif generation:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=200x200
&chdlp=b
&chtt=Uberman
&chdl=Asleep%7CAwake
&chd=t:1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11,1,11
&cht=p
&chco=4ECDC4,C7F464
&chan=1200
```

[image: animated charts Image]

Answer (score 0):

A few months back, my team actually created and shipped a product to solve this exact issue: [ChartURL.com](https://charturl.com).

ChartURL has a free tier, but it's not forever-free like Google Image Charts. That being said, we have some great features that make it a breeze to work with including:

- The concept of "Templates" which lets users design a chart style inside our web app and then be able to reference that template when creating the image instead of having to always pass in all their style options.
- A "Short URL API" which allows a developer create charts with as much data as they want without running into problems of the URL being too long.
- And we even have even started a pilot program for marketers that allows them to upload CSVs to us and get back an augmented CSV that includes image URLs they can use in with their email marketing software.

Comment: Hey Ryan -- it doesn't look like your product would work with Salesforce the way that the old Image Charts API does. Needing to encrypt the URL parameters means it can't be done from a formula field. If users have to use code or request headers or ANYTHING other than a query string parameter, they can just use the free google charting JS api.

Comment: Ah OK @ChristianCarter thanks for that clarification. I never thought it would be a drop-in replacement, but Ralph & Daniel's followup comments where they referenced exporting between different services gave me the impression that they might have the flexibility to use ChartURL somewhere along the way.

Comment: I was hoping your response would say "oh but we DO support pure URL based charts" :). If you have flexibility, your tool looks great and I will keep it in mind!

Comment: Haha well I mean there's nothing technical stopping us from doing that. But because we're pay-as-you-go, we need to be able to verify the authenticity of the request. If you're not looking to put images in emails, we could do something where we let you append an API key on the end of an image URL but limit what domains the image would render on using CORS, but that would still leave you open to potential fraud.

Comment: Hit enter too soon: I'm also more than happy to riff on ideas if you'd like to grab 15 minutes to chat: https://calendly.com/angilly/15min